# SFML SetFont segmentation fault crash

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm trying to load sf::Font to sf::Text and it crash with segmentation fault. Does any of you has idea why? (I'm using namespace sf by the way)

EDIT: added rest of class to question

Definition of class:

```
class CellButton{
    public:
    CellButton(int top_left_x, int top_left_y, string text);
    RectangleShape& getButton() {return cell_button;};
    void draw_self(RenderWindow& phone_window);
    private:
    int top_left_x;
    int top_left_y;
    Font buttonFont;
    Text buttonText;
    RectangleShape cell_button;
};
```

Constructor:

```
CellButton::CellButton(int top_left_x, int top_left_y, string text): top_left_x(top_left_x), top_left_y(top_left_y){
cell_button.setSize(Vector2f(button_size_x,button_size_y));
cell_button.setFillColor(Color::White);
cell_button.setOutlineThickness(1);
cell_button.setOutlineColor(Color::Black);
cell_button.setPosition(Vector2f(top_left_x,top_left_y));

if(!buttonFont.loadFromFile("./tiff/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf")) cerr<<"Error occurred at loading font"<<endl;
buttonText.setFont(buttonFont); // <- here occures segmentation fault
buttonText.setCharacterSize(24);
buttonText.setStyle(Text::Regular);
buttonText.setString("MIGHTY BUTTON!");
buttonText.setFillColor(Color::Black);
buttonText.setPosition(Vector2f(top_left_x/2,top_left_y/2));
```

Comment: There's a strong change that you're destructing the font before the text. Read [this](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Text.php#a2927805d1ae92d57f15034ea34756b81).

Comment: Call to setFont even when loadFromFile return error is not a good idea.

Comment: Check the application startup path because some IDE can change it, Try to use absolute path for font.

Comment: As noted by @tunglt, you are trying to set the button font even if loading it from the file fails. Do you see the error message before the segmentation fault crash?

Comment: @J-M. Gorius No, it loads font to buttonFont without any problem

Comment: I suspect that the segmentation fault happens later on in your code. The [`sf::Text::setFont`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php#a2927805d1ae92d57f15034ea34756b81) documentation states that `buttonFont` must exist as long as `buttonText` uses it.

Comment: Please provide more codes because we don't know the context of the crash (the lifetime of buttonFont and buttonText). We cannot guess how your program works.

Comment: @tunglt added definition and rest of constructor

Comment: Looked at sf::Text source code, setFont does almost nothing (just copy the address of the input font to its own pointer). If the program crashed, it must be an undefined behavior somewhere. I doubt that loadFromFile has an issue with your font, try to use a normal font to see if the program works.

Comment: Done some digging and found bug in different place. Thank all of you, all answers highly appreciated :)